# $C_{S_3}(A) = S_3$ implies $A \leq Z(S_3)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

On page 51 in Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote, we can read that if $C_{S_3}(A)$ were equal to $S_3$ then $A$ would be a subgroup of $Z(S_3)$. I don't understand why. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Can you describe $C_{S_{3}}(A)$ and $Z(S_3)$ in words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the definitions carefully, that is all. Suppose $G$ is a group, and $H$ is a subgroup. Then $C_G(H)$ is the collection of elements of $g\in G$ that commute with *every* $h\in H$. In particular $C_G(H)=G$ if and only if every element of $G$ commutes with every element of $H$, that is, $H$ lies in the centre of $G$, $Z(G)$, the set (subgroup) of elements of $G$ that commute with every element of $G$.